# Using regex and tidyr in R to split column variable on first instance of match

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

Trying to split a column in an R data frame that has more than one space in the variable, but I want to split on just the first space. An example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(game = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), date = c("Monday Apr 3", "Tuesday Apr 4", "Wednesday Apr 5", "Thursday Apr 6", "Friday Apr 7", "Saturday Apr 8"))
```

I'm trying to use tidyr to split the df 'date' column on just the first space so that the day is in its own column:

```
  game       day date
1    1    Monday  Apr 3
2    2   Tuesday  Apr 4
3    3 Wednesday  Apr 5
4    4  Thursday  Apr 6
5    5    Friday  Apr 7
6    6  Saturday  Apr 8
```

The above is the problem. The below is what I've tried and what is going wrong.

By the tidyr documentation, the default value of 'sep' is 'a regular expression that matches any sequence of non-alphanumeric values.' So if I just do:

```
df %>% separate(date, c("day", "date"))
```

That will split on the space but it splits on both spaces(e.g. the space after 'Monday' and the space after 'Apr' in 'Monday Apr 3'). The result is:

```
  game       day date
1    1    Monday  Apr
2    2   Tuesday  Apr
3    3 Wednesday  Apr
4    4  Thursday  Apr
5    5    Friday  Apr
6    6  Saturday  Apr
Warning message:
Too many values at 6 locations: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

I can add the regex to select just the first space (and I checked that this regex worked in Sublime Text):

```
df %>% separate(date, c("day", "date"), sep='^[^\\s]*\\K\\s')
```

But that gives me:

```
  game             day date
1    1    Monday Apr 3 <NA>
2    2   Tuesday Apr 4 <NA>
3    3 Wednesday Apr 5 <NA>
4    4  Thursday Apr 6 <NA>
5    5    Friday Apr 7 <NA>
6    6  Saturday Apr 8 <NA>
Warning message:
Too few values at 6 locations: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

So what is going wrong? Or how do I make this work? Or what obvious thing am I not understanding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the `extra` parameter to be `merge`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(date, c("day", "date"), extra = "merge")

#  game       day  date
#1    1    Monday Apr 3
#2    2   Tuesday Apr 4
#3    3 Wednesday Apr 5
#4    4  Thursday Apr 6
#5    5    Friday Apr 7
#6    6  Saturday Apr 8
```

Comment: Thanks. Here (https://rdrr.io/cran/tidyr/man/separate.html) where it explains 'extra', it reads: "If sep is a character vector, this controls what happens when there are too many pieces." I thought a space wasn't a character vector. Clearly that was wrong/dumb/silly/etc. of me.

Answer (score 1):

Psidom has you covered with regard to your first warning message about too many values.  With regard to your second approach where you ended up with too few values, that's in part because `\\K` doesn't work with `stringi`, which is what is being used by `separate`.  You can check for yourself with `stringi::stri_split_regex(df$date, '^[^\\s]*\\K\\s')`.  So, you don't get any splits with that regex, and you end up with the warning message about too few values.

You could specify `sep` as

```
# a space not followed by a digit
df %>% separate(date, c("day", "date"), sep = "\\s(?!\\d)")
#  game       day  date
#1    1    Monday Apr 3
#2    2   Tuesday Apr 4
#3    3 Wednesday Apr 5
#4    4  Thursday Apr 6
#5    5    Friday Apr 7
#6    6  Saturday Apr 8
```

#### Some alternatives regular expressions:

You can't use `\\K`, but if you need to use a variable-length look-behind, the quantifier needs to be bounded:

```
# a space preceded by 3 - 6 characters and "day". 
# 3 - 6 characters allows "Monday" and "Wednesday"
"(?<=.{3,6}day)\\s"
# same idea
"(?<=\\S{3,6}day)\\s"
# same idea
"(?<=.?.?.?...day)\\s"
# same idea, but using ^ to anchor and not using "day"
"(?<=^\\S{0,9})\\s"
# space followed by some other characters, a space, digit(s) and the end of the line
"\\s(?=.+\\s\\d+$)"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this easily using `base R`

```
cbind(df[1], read.csv(text=sub("\\s+", ",", df$date),
             header=FALSE, col.names = c("day", "date")))
#  game       day  date
#1    1    Monday Apr 3
#2    2   Tuesday Apr 4
#3    3 Wednesday Apr 5
#4    4  Thursday Apr 6
#5    5    Friday Apr 7
#6    6  Saturday Apr 8
```

---

Or another option is `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, date, into = c("day", "date"), "(\\S+)\\s+(.*)")
#   game       day  date
#1    1    Monday Apr 3
#2    2   Tuesday Apr 4
#3    3 Wednesday Apr 5
#4    4  Thursday Apr 6
#5    5    Friday Apr 7
#6    6  Saturday Apr 8
```

Comment: As a side note, in R-devel and future releases, there is `strcapture` -- `cbind(df[1], strcapture("(\\S+)\\s+(.*)", as.character(df$date), data.frame(day = "", date = "")))`

Comment: @alexis_laz Thank you for the `str_capture`